# Sum not working in Linq when the variable to be calculated is string

Tags: c#, linq

```
IdGroup       Quantity
-----------------------
1             22
2             1
3             4
```

I want to sum up all the quantities - so the answer should be `27`

The class is:

```
public class lines 
{
   int IdGroup {get; set}
   string Quantity {get; set}
}
```

Given is an list of `line`s:

```
List<lines> lines_array = ...
```

Quantity is a `string`, for some internal reasons.

I don't know how I can use `Sum` here because of this.

I tried with:

```
int total_quantity = 
    lines_array
    .GroupBy(grp => grp.IdGroup)
    .Select(grp => new { mysumatory = grp.Sum(o => o.Quantity });
```

But this don't work.

Can you help me?

Comment: you need to parse the strings to integers.

Comment: why is the quantity a `string`? ... Your problems begins there

Comment: Why would you expect `Sum` to work as you expect with a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
int total_quantity = lines_array.Sum(l=>int.Parse(l.Quantity));
```

I don't understand why you group the entries if you want to calculate the total number of quantities.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Int32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
int total_quantity = lines_array
        .GroupBy(grp => grp.IdGroup)
        .Select(grp => new { mysumatory = grp.Sum(o => int.Parse(o.Quantity)) });
```

Comment: He doesnt want the sum of the group but of all entries I think

Answer (score 1):

you need to parse the string:

```
.Select(grp => new { mysumatory = grp.Sum(o => int.Parse(o.Quantity )});
```

Alternative with `TryParse` just in case, theres invalid data in quantity, which cannot be parsed to int:

```
.Select(grp => new { mysumatory = grp.Sum(s => {
        int outvalue;
        if (int.TryParse(s.Quantity, out outvalue))
            return outvalue;
        else
            return 0;
    });
```

Comment: He doesnt want the sum of the group but of all entries I think

Comment: @T_D: I do not think it matters, if we sum the grouping or everything, because the culprit is the string to int conversion. If he wants to Sum  every entry, he just needs to remove the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to either use Int32.Parse(o.Quantity), or perform a conversion of quantity on your linq query. As it is only used for sum I will go with the former.